# IntelliJ idea thinks that my project is external

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, elementary-os

I am using elementary OS and I have installed and activated a copy of IntelliJ.

When I try to refactor and try to change the name of a file I get the following error. (Note the test.txt tab is brown indicating it's outside the project.)

Also note I have done an `ls -la` to show the `.idea` folder is in the directory.

> Cannot perform refactoring. Selected folder is not located inside the project
>
> [image: image of error above]

Answer (score 1):

The project configuration looks broken. You can try to do the following:

- Close the project. `File | Close Project`
- Close the IDE.
- Open the project directory in the OS file explorer and delete all `.iml` files and the `.idea` directory.
- Re-import the project into IntelliJ from [Existing sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#open-project).